# Codewars javascript task - help to understand

Tags: javascript

I am taking an [excercise on codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d81488b981293527000c8f/train/javascript):

> Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two
>   values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up
>   to form the sum.
>   Example:

```
sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5],         10)
#              ^-----------^   5 + 5 = 10, indices: 1, 5
#                    ^--^      3 + 7 = 10, indices: 3, 4 *
#  * entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [3, 7]
```

What do you think **entire pair is earlier** means? IMO if the sum of it's indexes is smallest. Now based on this assumption I made my solution and one test fails:

```js
    var sum_pairs=function(ints, s){
      let i = 0;
      let pair = [0, 0];
      let ind = [100, 100]
      let found = false;
      
      function loop(i) {
     if (i > ints.length) return pair;
        ints.slice(i).forEach((curr, idx) => {
          ints.slice(i+1).some((num, i) => {
            let sum = curr + num;
            let prevIndicies = ind[0] + ind[1];
            if(sum === s && prevIndicies > idx + i) {
              ind = [idx, i];
              pair = [curr, num];
              found = true;
              return true;
            }
          })
        })
        i += 1;
        loop(i)
      }
      loop(0)
      if (found) {
      return pair  
      }
      return undefined;
    }
    console.log(sum_pairs([1,4,8,7,3,15], 8))
```

Test returns error that `[1, 7]` is expected.

Comment: That is an incredibly badly worded question.

Comment: Can you give a hint why? For me seems good because `some` stops looping the array if founds results, though `forEach` still goes all the way, so here might be a place for improvement. + it looks ugly, I know. That was the way I could think of...

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean your question, which is fine, I mean the codewars question is badly worded (as evidenced by the fact that you have to post here to figure it out - yep, it's not clear what they mean)

Comment: My read of this is that the "entire pair is earlier" phrase refers to the fact that the 3, and 7 are both encountered in the array first earlier than the two 5s when the array is parse from the left as per the instruction.

Comment: I agree with @PaulCurtis, the answer is the FIRST PAIR that you encounter in the array, so if you have [ 1, 3, 4, 6, 7 ] 10, your first "entire pair" is 4+6 and not 3+7

Comment: When I run your code snippet, you are returning the 4 twice, even though it's only in the supplied array once.

Comment: @Paul Curtis - indeed... Just changed `ints.slice(i+1)` to `ints.slice(i+2)` and all my tests passes... Now I am super confused. Though I still can't submit solution because timout accures.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what it means is they want the *second element* to be as leftward in the list as possible. For example, for

```
l5= [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5];
```

when trying to find a sum of 10, the desired output is

```
[3, 7]
[10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5];
           ^  ^
```

instead of

```
[5, 5]
[10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5];
     ^           ^
```

because the last element in `[3, 7]`, the 7, came before the second 5.

This code seems to pass all test cases - iterate in a triangular fashion, starting at indicies `[0, 1]`, `[0, 2]`, `[1, 2]`, `[0, 3]`, `[1, 3]`, `[2, 3]`, ...:

```
const sum_pairs = function(ints, s){
  const { length } = ints;
  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (ints[i] + ints[j] === s) return [ints[j], ints[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const sum_pairs=function(ints, s){
  const { length } = ints;
  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (ints[i] + ints[j] === s) return [ints[j], ints[i]];
    }
  }
}

l1= [1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15];
l2= [1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1];
l3= [20, -13, 40];
l4= [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0];
l5= [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5];
l6= [4, -2, 3, 3, 4];
l7= [0, 2, 0];
l8= [5, 9, 13, -3];


console.log(sum_pairs(l1, 8))
console.log(sum_pairs(l2, -6))
console.log(sum_pairs(l3, -7))
console.log(sum_pairs(l4, 2))
console.log(sum_pairs(l5, 10))
console.log(sum_pairs(l6, 8))
console.log(sum_pairs(l7, 0))
console.log(sum_pairs(l8, 10))
```

Comment: Thank you for the destrucuring of array property values. Never used it like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

It means that you go from left to right and take the first matching pair, and since 7 is the first element that creats a pair (going from the left) 3 and 7 is the first pair.

I would solve it a bit easier:

```
function sum_pairs(arr, target) {
    let old = [];
    let result = [];
    arr.some((el) => {
        let found = old.find((oldEl) => oldEl + el === target);
        if (found) return result = [found, el];
        old.push(el);
    })
    return result;
}

sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10);
```

**Edit**: an explaination. I loop over all elements in the array searching for a match i all the elements I have passed. If I find a match I remember it and break out of the loop by returning a "truthy" value. (That is just how .some() works.) Finally if I have not found a match I add the element to my list of old elements and go on to the next.

Comment: It said nothing of negative numbers. But sure it does. ```sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, -3, 13, 5], 10);```

Comment: This one is basically doing the same as the one you accepted, just using array operations instead of simple loops.

Answer (score -1):

```
function sum_pair(arr,sum){
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach((i, j)=>{
    if(i+arr[j+1]===sum){
        console.log(i,arr[j+1], i+arr[j+1])
    }
  })
}

sum_pair([0, 3, 7, 0, 5, 5],10)
```